# Opening Several Websites and screenshotting | GDI Error

Tags: powershell, gdi, bmp

I've created a PowerShell script that opens several websites located in an Excel Spreadsheet and takes screenshots of each one.

Here is the Code:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

function Screenshot([Drawing.Rectangle]$bounds, $path) {
   $bmp = New-Object Drawing.Bitmap $bounds.width, $bounds.height
   $graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)

   $graphics.CopyFromScreen($bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $bounds.size)

   $bmp.Save($path)

   $graphics.Dispose()
   $bmp.Dispose()
}

$data = Import-Excel 'C:\Temp\HostNames\HostNames.xlsx'

$data | ForEach-Object {
   $website = $_

   $url=$website.Hostnames.Split(',')[0]

   Write-Host $website.Name $url

   $IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
   $IE.visible=$true
   $IE.FullScreen=$false
   $IE.ToolBar = $false
   $IE.StatusBar = $false
   $IE.MenuBar = $false
   $IE.AddressBar = $true
   $IE.Resizable = $true
   $IE.Top = 0
   $IE.Left = 577
   $IE.Width = 1024
   $IE.Height = 747

   $IE.navigate2( $url )

   $i=0
   While ( $IE.busy -eq $true ) { 
      Start-Sleep -s 1
      $i = $i + 1
      if ( $i -ge 20 ) { break }
   }

   $bounds = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB($IE.Left, $IE.Top, $IE.Left + $IE.Width, $IE.Top + $IE.Height)

   $filename = "C:\Temp\HostNames\urlshots\"+ ($website.Name) +".png"

   Screenshot $bounds $filename

   $IE.Quit()
}
```

The problem is that I keep getting this error after each website has been run:

```
Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "A generic error occurred in GDI+."
At C:\Temp\HostNames\HostNames View.ps1:9 char:4
+    $bmp.Save($path)
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExternalException
```

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: Are you sure `$path` contains valid file name? No disallowed characters or the like? Does the `Screenshot` function work if invoked directly from command line?

Comment: As aside: create the `$IE` Com-object variable with all fixed properties stuff BEFORE the loop. Do `$IE.Quit()` AFTER the loop and release memory with `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($IE | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()`. As it is now, you creae a new object in every iteration and never clear it from memory. This will gobble-up your available RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... (as Theo is pointing to)

I just made a few tweaks to work on my side, since I did not want to do all the excel stuff.

Depending on what is on a computer screen, you have to bring the browser to the from as well, so, my tweaks add that.

```
[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing')
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')


function Screenshot([Drawing.Rectangle]$bounds, $path) 
{
   $bmp = New-Object Drawing.Bitmap $bounds.width, $bounds.height
   $graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)

   $graphics.CopyFromScreen($bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $bounds.size)

   $bmp.Save($path)

   $graphics.Dispose()
   $bmp.Dispose()
}

# Open the browser once
$IE = New-Object -ComObject internetexplorer.application
$IE.visible    = $true
$IE.FullScreen = $false
$IE.ToolBar    = $false
$IE.StatusBar  = $false
$IE.MenuBar    = $false
$IE.AddressBar = $true
$IE.Resizable  = $true
$IE.Top        = 0
$IE.Left       = 577
$IE.Width      = 1024
$IE.Height     = 747

$i = 0

While ( $IE.busy -eq $true ) 
{ 
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    $i = $i + 1

    if ( $i -ge 20 ) 
    { break }
}

# Read and process the data in the file
# Import-Excel -Path 'C:\Temp\HostNames\HostNames.xlsx' 

# Set focus on the browser
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate('Internet Explorer')

'microsoft.com','google.com','stackoverflow.com' |  
ForEach-Object {
<#
   $website = $_

   # Open an new site in a new tab, set focus on the tab
   $url = $website.Hostnames.Split(',')[0]
#>

   "Processing the website names $PSItem"
   $IE.navigate2( $PSItem )

   $bounds = [Drawing.Rectangle]::
   FromLTRB($IE.Left, $IE.Top, $IE.Left + $IE.Width, $IE.Top + $IE.Height)

   $filename = "D:\Temp\$($PSItem -replace '.com').png"

   # Take a screenshot
   Screenshot $bounds $filename
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
}

# Release resources
$IE.Quit()

[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($IE) | 
Out-Null 

[System.GC]::Collect() 
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\temp' -Filter '*.png'
<#
# Results

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        05-Mar-20     11:45         172410 google.png
-a----        05-Mar-20     11:45          17781 microsoft.png
-a----        05-Mar-20     11:45          50634 stackoverflow.png
#>
```